# Proper way to create a static virtual factory method in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, unity-game-engine, design-patterns

I'm implementing classes for Effects (something with a duration that applies a behavior in the FixedUpdate loop while it is active) in Unity3D.

I have a base abstract Effect class which has the behavior for keeping track of the duration, removing itself when the duration is up, and calling a protected abstract _doEffect function while its duration is up.  In my derived classes, I override _doEffect to create Effects with different behaviors.

```
public abstract class Effect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public virtual float kDuration { get { return 1.0f; }}
    public static bool IsStackable { get { return false; }}
    private float _elapsed = 0.0f;

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        _elapsed = kDuration;
    }

    protected virtual void FixedUpdate()
    {
        _elapsed -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        if(_elapsed <= 0) {
            Destroy(this);
        }

        _doEffect();
    }

    protected abstract void _doEffect();
}
```

Now, because you can't use constructors with Unity3D, I need a way to do the following for each derived Effect class when I'm applying a new Effect of that type to a game object:

1) If this type of effect is not stackable, then remove all other instances of this monobehaviour from the game object.
2) Create a new component of the effect type to the game object.
3) Do some initialization specific to that effect type.

For these requirements, I was imagining doing something like

```
public class DerivedEffect : Effect
{
    public override float kDuration { get {return 1.0f; }}
    public static bool IsStackable { get { return true; }}

    private int _derivedData;

    public static void Create(GameObject obj, int data)
    {
        DerivedEffect effect = DerivedEffect.CreateEffect(obj);
        effect._data = data;
    }

    protected override void _doEffect()
    {
        //Do some stuff
    }
}
```

and then in the base class putting

```
public static virtual Effect CreateEffect(GameObject obj)
{
    //T is somehow magically the type of the class you called this function on
    if(!T.IsStackable()) {
        //delete all components of type T on obj
    }
    T effect = obj.AddComponent<T>();
    return effect;
}
```

Obviously this isn't possible unless I do some weird stuff with generics and reflection that seems a bit extreme and probably not that right way to do things.

The crux is that I want a static function that does 1), 2), 3), and I want to share the code that does 1) and 2), and 1) depends on a bool which is different for every derived class.

What is a proper, working design for these desiderata?

Comment: How about marking stack-able effects with `IsStackable` interface then `if (effect is IsIstackable) { ... }`?

Comment: That's checking if an object is an IStackable, right?  Since DerivedEffect.CreateEffect(obj) is a static function, it wouldn't have an object to check.  Well, in this case since we're creating an object it would, it seems a bit strange to check it since really the bool in question is feature of the class, not a specific object.

Comment: We can also imagine cases where maybe based on a feature of the class we wouldn't want to instantiate the effect, and then instantiating the effect just to check it so that we can circumvent using a static property is a waste of memory and processing time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is a proper, working design for these desiderata?

Unity is component based and gets things complicated when you want to use it the way you in a normal C# application.

The simplest way is to use Composition. Make the `Effect` class it's own class that is not abstract. Just a normal class that inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. You can easily create new instance of it with `AddComponent` and get it with `GetComponent`. This script can also destroy itself directly after the timer is done counting without any problems.

Create a global variable in the `DerivedEffect` class to hold the instance of the `Effect` script that is created and this can be re-used over and over again until it becomes null which means that the script is destroyed. Note that there is no inheritance involved here and `DerivedEffect` script is only used as an example of the script that manages the `Effect` script.

Comment: How does this solve the problem of sharing the code for adding an effect based on the type of effect (stackable or not, possible based on max number of stacks later)?

Comment: I think I lost it with being `stackable` or not. What is that? When does the Object become stackable  and does it become un-stackable ?

Comment: Each type of effect (each derived class in the original design) is either stackable or not (meaning more than one can exist on the same game object at the same time or not).  Since it's a property of the type, I figured a static bool would make sense, but I didn't see a way to make that design work.

Comment: No, static is not good for this. Have a public variable in the `DerivedEffect` script that determines if it is "stackable" or not. When you want to query that use `GetComponent` to get the `DerivedEffect`  script then use check that public variable inside of it.

Comment: Sometimes we may not have an instance object to check, for example if we add a "castable" property to effects or something like that which determines where these effects can be creased as a result of a spell.  In this case, we'd need to check the type (class) to see if it makes sense to instantiate, and there's no actual object to check the public variable for.  It seems inefficient to instantiate one, check the property, and then delete it if it actually shouldn't be instantiated.

Comment: *"It seems inefficient to instantiate one, check the property, and then delete it if it actually shouldn't be instantiated"* No no no. I never said to do that. Use `GetComponent` to check if one exist. If it returns `null` then it does not exist.

Comment: What about the castable example?  Let's say each type of Effect has a bool that indicates whether it can be created from a spell or not.  Then how would you handle knowing whether you can instantiate it or not when there's no instance to check?